# _trackTiming google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, time-tracking

I have tried to track timing using this code in Google Analytics, and I have tried to find the report under "Behavior" --> "Site Speed" --> "User Timings"

but I can't find any result, can anyone help please ?

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackTiming', 'Start up', 'Load Data' , 100]);">Load Data</a>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of search I have found why my result is not shown, it is because the timing reports is a sampling reports which means that it needs a lot of data and hits to be able to calculate those reports, so it will take a lot of time until it be shown in your dashboard

Answer (score 0):

On the google analytics website Behavior -> Site speed -> User Timings

Remember that it can take 24 hours before the data becomes available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Enable sampling of 100% of the users who visit your site by changing the existing line to this one:

```
ga('create', 'UA-<your id here>', 'auto', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});
```

The default is to sample 1% of the users.